# Google Ads Budget Prediction SQL Logic - used in Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've been asked to look at the Google Ads data within my Big Query account - and without the use of any ML add-ons, I've been asked if I can predict performance depending on budget.

For example, If a client is spending £10k per month on their Google Ads, they are asking if they increased the budget by X% what impressions, cpa, cpc, and conversions would look like.

I have a feeling we can use SQL logic to understand the average of each metric, related to the budget. But I'm unaware how to do this within the SQL workspace.

Thanks in advance!

Here is an example of the data. - On the 10th August, my account spent £786.48. With that, we received over 65K impressions, with an average cpc of £0.56 and an average CPM of £12.01

- Date 10/08/2022
- Cost 786.48
- Impressions 65,495
- Average CPC 0.56
- Average CPM 12.01

What I would like to know, is, can I use SQL to take the data of previous days, months, years and predict the number of impressions, Average CPC and CPM if I was to change the budget. (Increase spend by 10% or decrease it by 10% what is likely to be the outcome)

Comment: Hi @Ian. You should try to break down your question and share some code with us.

Comment: HI SImon, I don't have the code, I'm looking for some advice on what code to write. I need to use SQL to predict the cpa, cpc, impressions from a google ads campaign if the budget is increased. Using the last year's worth of data.

Comment: When I say the code I mean share with us the SQL you've already written. start slow, take each problem one by one.

Comment: SQL is for data manipulation. You cant manipupate the data without having it first

Comment: thanks guys, I've updated the original question, hope that helps more?

Comment: Hi Ian,
I think you should think about the algorithm first.
Let's say you have a dataset in Excel. How would you make a decision based on the data you have. If you know it, then we can transform it into an algorithm.
After you have an algorithm, then it comes to SQL part.

Comment: Thanks Sabri, That makes sense - Ok, to start with if it cost £786 to get 65,000 impressions, how many impressions would we get if we increased the spend to £1000?